# In Photoshop, how can I manipulate flat text in a 3D environment while keeping text editable?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, 3d

As shown in this image, I have a stock photo of a calendar (viewed from an angle).

I then created a layer of text using a handwriting font.

I've been trying to use the 3D mode within Adobe Photoshop CC 2015 to adjust the perspective of the handwriting layer so that it almost looks like it's written directly onto the calendar.

However, I'm unable to edit the text after this 3D manipulation.

Here is what I did: I created the text layer, selected it, then Window > 3D > Create New 3D Object > Source is Selected Layer > Type is "3D Postcard".

But now the layer has a cube icon (it's now a 3D layer?) and doesn't seem to be editable text anymore.

Is there a way to edit text *after* manipulating it within 3D space? If yes, how?

[image]

Comment: Note: I've searched Google and elsewhere for an answer to my question, but the word "text" combined with "3D" tends to imply *3D text extrusion* (which is not what we're talking about here), so search results have tended to be irrelevant, and I've been unable to find a tutorial about my question.

Comment: You dont actually need a 3d layer to transform a flat thing in perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. 3D mode wasn't necessary.

1. Create layers.
2. Group them.
3. Select the group folder.
4. Convert it to Smart Object.
5. Edit > Perspective Warp.
6. Drag a rectangle.
7. Press Warp.
8. Drag some of the corners.
9. Press the ✔ check mark to save.
10. Editing the text (or any of the layers within the Smart Object) is still possible after double-clicking the Smart Object layer.  After editing, just save the new temporary file (which had been created for you in a new tab).

See [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2Jut0semFI) for help.

Answer (score 1):

On the 3D Panel you'll have a Text Object:

[image]

Look at its Properties:

[image]